# osx change file encoding (iconv) recursive

Tags: macos, shell, encoding, glob, iconv

I know I can convert a single file encoding under OSX using:

`iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 myfilename.xxx > myfilename-utf8.xxx`

I have to convert a bunch of files with a specific extension,
so I want to convert file encoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8
for all *.ext files in folder /mydisk/myfolder

perhaps someobe know the syntax how to do this

thanks

ekke

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Adam' comment showed me the way how to resolve it,
but this was the only syntax I made it work:

```
find /mydisk/myfolder -name \*.xxx -type f | \
    (while read file; do
        iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "${file%.xxx}-utf8.xxx";
    done);
```

-i ... -o ... doesnt work, but >

thx again

ekke

Comment: For overwriting founded files `#!/bin/bash
find ./tmp -type f | \
    (while read file; do
        iconv -f windows-1251 -t UTF-8 "$file" -o "$file";
    done);
`

Comment: Thanks. I't helped me so much. I made so `#!/bin/bash 
find ./src -type f | \
(while read file ; do
 if [[ "$file" != *.DS_Store* ]]; then
  if [[ "$file" != *-utf8* ]]; then
   iconv -f CP1251 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "$file-utf8";
   rm $file;
   mv "$file-utf8" "$file";
  fi 
 fi
done);`

Comment: Thank you. This is what worked for me (1 line of code):
`find ./ -name AppLocalization.resx -type f | (while read file; do iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 AppLocalization.resx > "AppLocalization-UTF-8.resx"; done);`

Answer (score 3):

if your shell is bash, something like this

```
for files in /mydisk/myfolder/*.xxx
do
  iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$files" "${files%.xxx}-utf8.xxx"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is example Tested in mac 10.10.
Find file by name,convert encode ,then replace original file.work perfect. 
Thanks for Roman Truba's example,COPY the full code below to your shell script.

```
   #!/bin/bash
        find ./ -name *.java -type f | \
        (while read file;
            do if [[ "$file" != *.DS_Store* ]]; then
            if [[ "$file" != *-utf8* ]]; then
                iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "$file-utf8";
                rm $file;
                echo mv "$file-utf8" "$file";
                mv "$file-utf8" "$file";
            fi
        fi 
        done);
```

Comment: I had to change it to: find ./ -name "*.java" -type f
Otherwise it wouldn't wortk recursively

Answer (score 1):

try this ... it´s tested and workin:

First step (ICONV):
find /var/www/ -name *.php -type f | (while read file; do iconv -f ISO-8859-2 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "${file%.php}.phpnew"; done)

Second step (REWRITE - MV):
find /var/www/ -name "*.phpnew" -type f | (while read file; do mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\.\)phpnew/\1php/'` ; done)

It´s just conclusion on my research :)

Hope it helps
Jakub Rulec

Answer (score 1):

I extended Albert.Qings script:

- autodetect the current file encoding
- added a command parameter to do a dry/exec-run
- added a parameter for the directory and filename pattern

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  command=${1-"usage"}
  searchPattern=${2-"*.java"}
  searchDirectory=${3-"."}
  if [[ "$command" == "usage" ]]; then
      echo "convert-file-to-utf8.sh [usage|dry|exec] [searchPattern=$searchPattern] [searchDirectory=$searchDirectory]"
      exit
  fi
  find $searchDirectory -type f -name "$searchPattern" | \
  (while read file;
      do if [[ "$file" != *.DS_Store* ]]; then
      if [[ "$file" != *-utf8* ]]; then
          currentEncoding="$(file --brief --mime-encoding $file)"
          if [[ "$currentEncoding" != "utf-8" ]]; then
             echo "command:$command / iconv -f $currentEncoding -t UTF-8 $file"
             if [[ "$command" == "exec" ]]; then
               iconv -f $currentEncoding -t UTF-8 "$file" > "$file-utf8";
               rm $file;
               echo mv "$file-utf8" "$file";
               mv "$file-utf8" "$file";
            fi
          fi
      fi
  fi
  done);
  ```

Tested on MacOS X 10.12.6 / Sierra.

Comment: How could I change this script so it would accept files with spaces in the filename? Thanks. frank

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script in any scripting language to iterate over every file in /mydisk/myfolder, check the extension with the regex [.(.*)$], and if it's "ext", run the following (or equivalent) from a system call.

"iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8" + file.getName() + ">" + file.getName() + "-utf8.xxx"

This would only be a few lines in Python, but I leave it as an exercise to the reader to go through the specifics of looking up directory iteration and regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it recursively, you can use [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find /mydisk/myfolder -name \*.xxx -type f | \
    (while read file; do
        iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 -i "$file" -o "${file%.xxx}-utf8.xxx
    done)
```

Note that I've used `| while read` instead of the `-exec` option of find (or piping into `xargs`) because of the manipulations we need to do with the filename, namely, chopping off the `.xxx` extension (using `${file%.xxx}`) and adding `-utf8.xxx`.